# Disable keylistener in java

Tags: java, canvas, awt, keylistener, thread-sleep

In my program i have keyListener set on my canvas. It is working great, but when I do Thread.sleep(1000) keyListener is still listening and reading keys, but result shows only when sleep time has ended. How to make keyListener not to read or listen keys typed in sleep period?

Comment: By 'canvas' do you mean a `java.awt.Canvas`?  Please be specific and use the correct case for J2SE class names.  Also, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `Thread.sleep()` with Swing. From the question, I deduct you are doing everything at EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). So if you put EDT to sleep, it won't disable Swing, it will just pause these events for a second.

You can set up a Timer for one second, and when you need to stop receiving key events, just disable the component by `setEnabled(false)`, then start the timer, and when it runs out, you call `setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: I've already tried doing setEnabled(false) on canvas before and setEnabled(true) after, but keylistener still reads keys.

Comment: Does disabling a component block mouse events?  I know it blocks an `ActionListener` from firing, expect it would have no effect on a `MouseMotionListener` (the listener would still fire events), but am not sure about `MouseListener`.

Comment: @YanIvanEvdokimov do you have some custom KeyListener there? As far as I know, Canvas has no KeyListeners by its own. So can't you just update your KeyListener to ignore stuff for a second?

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I don't believe so. setEnabled() I think disables user controls (such as action for JButton, key listeners for text fields, etc...) - those are listeners inside Swing that you cannot change. For custom listeners, you must take care about (almost) everything.

Comment: I have: this keylistener: `canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { CODE } });`

Comment: Then just add `if(!((Canvas)e.getSource()).isEnabled()) return;` (Don't forget to call the setEnabled first.)